# unable to read cookie done with res.cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

Currently I'm messing around with JWT tokens, authentication and authorization. I'm creating a JWT token and refresh tokens. I set the refresh token in a cookie. Creating and logging in a user works as intended. However trying to refresh the token and updating it, it goes wrong.

**/login**

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), (req, res, next) => {
    const token = getToken({
        _id: req.user._id
    })
    const refreshToken = getRefreshToken({
        _id: req.user._id
    })
    User.findById(req.user._id).then(
        user => {
            user.refreshToken.push({
                refreshToken
            })
            user.save((err, user) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.statusCode = 500
                    res.send(err)
                } else {
                    res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, COOKIE_OPTIONS)
                    res.send({
                        success: true,
                        token
                    })
                }
            })
        },
        err => next(err)
    )
})
```

**/refreshToken**

```
router.post("/refreshToken", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("in refreshtoken")
    const { signedCookies = {} } = req;
    const { refreshToken } = signedCookies

    console.log(refreshToken)

    if (refreshToken) {
        try {
            const payload = jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET)
            const userId = payload._id
            User.findOne({
                _id: userId
            }).then(
                user => {
                    if (user) {
                        // Find the refresh token against the user record in database
                        const tokenIndex = user.refreshToken.findIndex(
                            item => item.refreshToken === refreshToken
                        )

                        if (tokenIndex === -1) {
                            res.statusCode = 401
                            res.send("Unauthorized1")
                        } else {
                            const token = getToken({
                                _id: userId
                            })
                            // If the refresh token exists, then create new one and replace it.
                            const newRefreshToken = getRefreshToken({
                                _id: userId
                            })
                            user.refreshToken[tokenIndex] = {
                                refreshToken: newRefreshToken
                            }
                            user.save((err, user) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    res.statusCode = 500
                                    res.send(err)
                                } else {
                                    res.cookie("refreshToken", newRefreshToken, COOKIE_OPTIONS)
                                    res.send({
                                        success: true,
                                        token
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    } else {
                        res.statusCode = 401
                        res.send("Unauthorized2")
                    }
                },
                err => next(err)
            )
        } catch (err) {
            res.statusCode = 401
            res.send("Unauthorized3")
        }
    } else {
        res.statusCode = 403
        res.send("Unauthorized4")
    }
})
```

**Cookie options**

```
exports.COOKIE_OPTIONS = {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: false,
  signed: false,
  maxAge: eval(process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRY) * 1000,
  sameSite: "none",
}
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState("login")
  const [userContext, setUserContext] = useContext(UserContext)

  const verifyUser = useCallback(() => {
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT + "users/refreshToken", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    }).then(async response => {
      console.log(response)
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        setUserContext(oldValues => {
          return { ...oldValues, token: data.token }
        })
      } else {
        setUserContext(oldValues => {
          return { ...oldValues, token: null }
        })
      }
      // call refreshToken every 20 seconds to renew the authentication token. Make it longer for prod.
      setTimeout(verifyUser, 20000)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }, [setUserContext])

  useEffect(() => {
    verifyUser()
  }, [verifyUser])

  /**
   * Sync logout across tabs
   */
  const syncLogout = useCallback(event => {
    if (event.key === "logout") {
      // If using react-router-dom, you may call history.push("/")
      window.location.reload()
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("storage", syncLogout)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", syncLogout)
    }
  }, [syncLogout])

  return userContext.token === null ? (
    <Card elevation="1">
      <Tabs id="Tabs" onChange={setCurrentTab} selectedTabId={currentTab}>
        <Tab id="login" title="Login" panel={<Login />} />
        <Tab id="register" title="Register" panel={<Register />} />
        <Tabs.Expander />
      </Tabs>
    </Card>
  ) : userContext.token ? (
    <Welcome />
  ) : (
    <Loader />
  )
}
```

I'm unsure what causes it that when I `console.log(refreshToken)` in `/refreshToken` it comes out as undefined. I also tried looking it up in any responses in the developer tools but couldn't find it.

Would really appreciate if anyone has some clarity about what might cause this issue.

Comment: Have you defined a `cookie-parser` through the express route? -> `app.use(require("cookie-parser"));`

Comment: I did yes, it is located in the index.js file.

Comment: @Stylent maybe your browser doesn't send the cookie because of your cookie config. You have ```sameSite``` set to "none", and secure to "false". I'm not sure but I think that violates the security defaults of most browsers. I assume you're running on localhost now, so maybe try setting ```sameSite``` to lax or strict.